# is GO source code uploaded to google app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I'm wondering if the source code is uploaded or only the binary / compiled version ?
Do GAE engineers have access to my precious source code ?

Answer (score 9):

Yes it uploads the source code and you can also download the source code of a specific version you previously deployed. You can also PERMANENTLY disable such a feature in the admin page. 
Don't worry to upload it, besides having strict SLA no one really cares about your code.

Comment: +1 for “no one really cares about your code” because it’s so true. :)

Comment: @rightføld I wouldn't be that sure with all the juniors working now at Google.

Answer (score 2):

The source code appears to be uploaded as well, according to "Downloading source code" in [Uploading, Downloading, and Managing a Go App](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/tools/uploadinganapp).  You could prove it by trying to download the source code yourself.